# Sleep second display

Tags: thunderbolt-display, dual-screen

I have an iMac with a Thunderbolt display attached.

I know I can force both displays to sleep by pressing ctrl-shift-eject.

How can I force only one display, the Thunderbolt one, to sleep?

I do not use both displays all the time and sometimes I just don't want to waste the electricity.

Comment: I do not think that it can be done via the OS. I personally just turn off the second monitor and grumble when I loose the mouse pointer on the monitor that is turned off.

Comment: Cannot turn of a Thunderbolt display. Apple stuff is not that easy to use yet. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct control of this for an individual screen in Mac OS as you also can't go the other way round and turn off the laptop-display to only use the external one without closing the lid and keeping it closed.

I guess you have to not plug in your external monitor if you don't want to use it.

Comment: Thunderbolt cables are not so easily removed and quickly reconnected. Too bad.